# How to get the URL in JS to a specific point from the Python backend to send/receive data

Tags: javascript, python, url, web-applications, backend

I am building my first webapp and still working locally.
I don't know how to make `.js` interact with `.py` backend. More specifically, I wont to know the way to get the URL to a specific point from the backend.

This is my `app.js`. It receives values(`company` and `category`) entered by a user and sends it to a Python backend. It then receives a data from the backend, to display in the UI. So my question is specifically to `let url = ...` part.

```
let params = {
        'company':some_value,
        'category':some_value
};

// here I wanna get a backend url from ('/get_table') 
let url = someFunctionToGetUrl('/get_table') + '/' + JSON.stringify(params);

let promise = fetch(url, init) 
                   .then(function(response) {
                       response.json()
                       .then(function(data){
                         // do something with the data
                       })
                   });
};
```

This is my `backend.py`. It receives values(`company` and `category`) from `.js` and filter the dataset, and returns the data to `.js`.

```
@app.route('/get_table/<path:params>')
def get_table(params):
    params_dict = json.loads(params)
    selected_company = params_dict.get('company')[0]
    selected_category = params_dict.get('category')
    df = pd.read_csv("tweet.csv")
    df_sorted = df[(df.product_id == selected_company) & (df.group == selected_category)]
    data = { 'table' : df_sorted }
    return json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: You trying to generate the hostname:port  dynamically? You should try use env variable with hostname/port to backend

Comment: Could you explain me how to do it? Sorry I'm quite noob in JS. I tried `process.env.PORT` but since i'm not using Node.js it didn't work...